# How to show uploaded photos in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using the carrierwave gem and I am trying to setup in the controller to display all the photos that have been uploaded (inside Photos table) using the box version in the view. I seem to only be able to show photos from selected users, but I want to show all uploads.

Photos controller:

```
  def new 
    @photo = Photo.new
  end

  def create
    @photo = Photo.create(params[:photo])
    @photo.user = current_user
    if @photo.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created photos."
      redirect_to :back
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def resize(width, height, gravity = 'Center')
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.combine_options do |cmd|
        cmd.resize "#{width}"
        if img[:width] < img[:height]
          cmd.gravity gravity
          cmd.background "rgba(255,255,255,0.0)"
          cmd.extent "#{width}x#{height}"
        end
      end
      img = yield(img) if block_given?
      img
    end
  end

  def edit
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    if @photo.update_attributes(paramas[:photo])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated photo."
      redirect_to @photo.gallery
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    @photo.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed photo."
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def avatar
    if current_user.update_attribute(:avatar_id, params[:id])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully made Avatar."
        else
          flash[:notice] = "Avatar failed"
        end
        redirect_to :back, notice: "Set as avatar!"
      end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I think you need an index method in your controller

```
def index
  @photos = Photo.all
end
```

And in your view if you want to show all the photos then you have to loop

```
- @photos.each do |photo|
   =image_tag photo.content_url
```

[Carrierwave Documentation](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)